# android convert from rgb to hsv and viceversa

Tags: android, colors, rgb, hsv

someone can explain why the conversion from rgb to hsv doesn't give the same result when convert back from hsv to rgb?

```
int color = Color.rgb(206, 43, 55);

int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
System.out.println(red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
//prints: 206, 43, 55 (as expected)

float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(red, green, blue, hsv);

float hue = hsv[0];
float sat = hsv[1];
float val = hsv[2];

int outputColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
red = Color.red(outputColor);
green = Color.green(outputColor);
blue = Color.blue(outputColor);
System.out.println(red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);

//prints: 206, 42, 54 (green and blue are changed)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
There seems to be a strange approximation in the android implementation of `android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV`.
The approximated value is exactly the Hue that in this implementation goes from 0° to 360°.

I found the code of java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB where the HUE goes from 0.0f to 1.0f and the conversion works well. So is not a float precision bug but an implementation bug, infact by multipling the `Hue * 360f` I get the correct HSV Hue value.

Answer (score 7):

If someone looking around the conversion from RGB to HSV and vice versa in Kotlin language:

```kotlin
// define array and color
var hsv = FloatArray(3)
var currentColor = Color.rgb(206, 43, 55);
```

```kotlin
// RGB to HSV
Color.colorToHSV(currentColor, hsv)

// hsv[0] --> hue
// hsv[1] --> saturation
// hsv[2] --> value
```

```kotlin
// HSV to RGB
currentColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv)

// assign red, green and blue
r = Color.red(currentColor)
g = Color.green(currentColor)
b = Color.blue(currentColor)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
```

I guess that's enough to answer your question, the result of the conversion is in HSV with range `[0.0, 1.0]` so you are dealing with finite precision, hence converting it back doesn't give the exact same value.

Comment: I also thought that the reason was this. Do you know any other method for exact conversion?

Answer (score -3):

Fix using this:

```
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(red, green, blue, hsv);

float hue = hsv[0];
float sat = hsv[1];
float val = hsv[2];

// i delete this part
/*int outputColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
red = Color.red(outputColor);
green = Color.green(outputColor);
blue = Color.blue(outputColor);*/

//use only this to get correct values (HSV)
System.out.println(hue + ", " + sat+ ", " + val);
```